# Power Automate - Copy files from a folder if they appear within an Excel spreadsheet list

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I am trying to use Power Automate to retrieve a large list of files (200+) from a data archive folder (71K files). I have a list of the file names I need to retrieve and am attempting to match and copy all files in the spreadsheet. Flow is as follows...
[image]

However, the flow fails at the point of trying to match filenames in the list with those in the target folder - "Can't retrieve the list of files. Illegal characters in path". Full error below...

"Correlation Id: 390dc828-eb79-4107-9625-4903c8f7b37f
Illegal characters in path.: Microsoft.PowerPlatform.PowerAutomate.Desktop.Actions.SDK.ActionException: Can't retrieve list of files in folder E:\2021\POD. ---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
at System.IO.Path.InternalCombine(String path1, String path2)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.GetFullSearchString(String fullPath, String searchPattern) at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption) at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Folder.Actions.FolderActions.GetFilesInFolder(Variant folder, Variant fileMask, Variant& listOfFiles, Boolean includeSubfolders, Boolean getResultInDataTable, String resultDataTableColumns, Boolean failOnAccessDenied) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Folder.Actions.GetFilesInFolder.Execute(ActionContext context) at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.ActionRunner.Run(IActionStatement statement, Dictionary`2 inputArguments, Dictionary`2 outputArguments)"

Any ideas where I am going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: From the error message there is an illegal character in the file name eg. * ' ` ~ etc.. what is the value of `CurrentItem` ?

Comment: There are 200 rows in the spreadsheet but they are all structured as per the below examples... 
25180326012021-060101.jpg
25180027012021-020440.jpg
25550601032021-011742.jpg
25550401032021-011830.jpg
25563403032021-110054.jpg
25561303032021-110058.jpg
25565603032021-015804.jpg
25580903032021-020010.jpg
25566303032021-020012.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using the `ExcelData`, `List` and `Get files in folder` actions are not quite correct.

What you are doing is adding the whole of the `ExcelData` into the first item of the `List`

What the `Get files in folder` then tries to match with is text to the effect of '[200 Rows, 1 column]' and not each file individually.

You can get rid of the `Create List` and `Add item to list` altogether. The `ExcelData` is already a List object so in your `For Each` loop you can replace `List` with `ExcelData`

[image: flow]

This assumes the excel data looks like this:

[image: exceldata]

Comment: Perfect, now working. Thank you @CobyC